# FluentAssertions Recursion Depth Reached in object with recursive structure

Tags: c#, unit-testing, recursion, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to unit test an object that recursively represents a directory structure, but even at the simplest level the fluentAssertions `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` is failing with *The maximum recursion depth was reached*.

How should this test be written to correctly get the test to pass.

Additionally, if child nodes were added, how do I stop the `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` infinitely re-comparing the parent `DirectoryNode`?

Here is the code, it is using `Xunit`, `FluentAssertions` and `System.IO.Abstractions` libraries.

The test:

```C#
[Fact]
public void DirectoryTreeBuilder_BuildTree_String_TopNodeTest()
{
    // Arrange
    string path = "C:\\";

    var mockFileSystem = new MockFileSystem();
    mockFileSystem.AddDirectory(path);

    var expected = new DirectoryNode
    {
        Info = mockFileSystem.DirectoryInfo.FromDirectoryName(path),
        Children = new List<DirectoryNode>()
    };

    // Act
    var builder = new DirectoryTreeBuilder(mockFileSystem);
    var calculated = builder.BuildTree(path);

    // Assert
    calculated.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

DirectoryNode properties class:

```C#
public class DirectoryNode
{
    public DirectoryNode Parent { get; set; }
    public DirectoryInfoBase Info { get; set; }
    public List<DirectoryNode> Children { get; set; }
    public List<FileInfoBase> Files => Info.GetFiles().ToList();
}
```

Tree Builder:

```C#
public class DirectoryTreeBuilder
{
    private readonly IFileSystem fileSystem;

    public DirectoryTreeBuilder(IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    public DirectoryTreeBuilder() : this(new FileSystem())
    {
    }

    public DirectoryNode BuildTree(string path)
    {
        var directoryInfo = fileSystem.DirectoryInfo.FromDirectoryName(path);

        return BuildTree(directoryInfo);
    }

    public DirectoryNode BuildTree(DirectoryInfoBase directoryInfo)
    {
        var node = new DirectoryNode
        {
            Info = directoryInfo,
        };

        var directories = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();
        var children = new List<DirectoryNode>();

        // Process list of child directories
        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            var child = BuildTree(directory);
            child.Parent = node;

            children.Add(child);
        }

        node.Children = children;

        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than ten levels of directories? Did you try `AllowingInfiniteRecursion` option?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight there is a possibility that the directory structure could have more than 10 levels; but for the tests I don't have that many. I tried `AllowingInfiniteRecursion`, but that causes the process to eventually abort unexpectedly (it shouldn't be needed with this test).

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, the `DirectoryNode.Info` property holds a `DirectoryInfoBase` which is just a wrapper for a `DirectoryInfo` object.

`DirectoryInfo` has the property `Root` which at the highest level (such as C:\) will just return itself. This is the element that FluentAssertions `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` recursively fails on.

Unfortunately it doesn't appear that `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` can ignore sub-properties.